# WebKit on Emacs (does not found python-epc)

Tags: emacs, webkit

I'm trying to install WEbkit on emacs following the emacswiki page [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WebKit). It asks me to install pyqt5,python-xlib, and python EPC. I've installed the first two via apt-get and epc via python pip utility (debian like distribution). It installs on epc in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/epc`.

I've copied all the webkits files on `~/.emacs.d/webkit` and added the next to the end of the `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/webkit/")
(require 'epc)
(load "webkit.el")
```

When I open emacs, it looks like it tried to load it, and displays the error message:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/user/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, epc

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

I don't know which epc file it's trying to look for and where. `epc` looks properly installed, as I can import it from a python interpreter.

Comment: Emacs is looking for `epc.el` (or the compiled file, `epc.elc`) in the directories listed in `load-path`. (Check which ones with `C-h v load-path`.)

Comment: @legoscia But there is no `epc.el` file on my computer. installing `epc`didn't create one, and there is not one in the `epc` repository. Should I produce it somehow from the installation?

Comment: It seems to be in this project: https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-epc